Why my CSS image carousel/slideshow drags to the top of the page each time when activated?
I created a template for my store with the image carousel/slideshow. Everything worked great but when pasted into eBay it's not anymore. When I click on the arrows or page 2, page 3, etc it drags me to the top of the eBay page.
https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/134131787992
slideshow code below:

    <div class="container">
        <div data-am-fadeshow="quick-nav prev-next-nav">

            <!-- Radio -->
            <input type="radio" name="css-fadeshow" id="slide-1" />
            <input type="radio" name="css-fadeshow" id="slide-2" />
            <input type="radio" name="css-fadeshow" id="slide-3" />
            <input type="radio" name="css-fadeshow" id="slide-4" />

            <!-- Slides -->
            <div class="fs-slides">
                <div class="fs-slide" style="background-image: url(https://m.media-amazon.com/images/S/aplus-media-library-service-media/c93f0d76-b1ea-4f60-8c62-964668228fad.__CR0,0,1464,600_PT0_SX1464_V1___.png);">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="fs-slide" style="background-image: url(https://m.media-amazon.com/images/S/aplus-media-library-service-media/bca360ed-6f3a-4051-8eb5-d87d5eac2474.__CR0,0,1464,600_PT0_SX1464_V1___.png);">
          
                </div>
                <div class="fs-slide" style="background-image: url(https://m.media-amazon.com/images/S/aplus-media-library-service-media/b0ec28be-393b-4a58-abf3-1cdc82e1e892.__CR0,0,1464,600_PT0_SX1464_V1___.png);">
          
                </div>
                <div class="fs-slide" style="background-image: url(https://m.media-amazon.com/images/S/aplus-media-library-service-media/3902d731-3cff-4f31-91c4-1ae4b94128a8.__CR0,0,1464,600_PT0_SX1464_V1___.png);">
                </div>
        
            </div>

            <!-- Quick Navigation -->
            <div class="fs-quick-nav">
                <label class="fs-quick-btn" style=background-color: #ddd; display: inline; margin: 20px
               for="slide-1">2.5kg-15kg Set</label>
                <label class="fs-quick-btn" for="slide-2">5kg-25kg Set</label>
                <label class="fs-quick-btn" for="slide-3">5kg-30kg Set</label>
                <label class="fs-quick-btn" for="slide-4">1kg-10kg Set</label>
            </div>

            <!-- Prev Navigation -->
            <div class="fs-prev-nav">
                <label class="fs-prev-btn" for="slide-1"></label>
                <label class="fs-prev-btn" for="slide-2"></label>
                <label class="fs-prev-btn" for="slide-3"></label>
                <label class="fs-prev-btn" for="slide-4"></label>
            </div>

            <!-- Next Navigation -->
            <div class="fs-next-nav">
                <label class="fs-next-btn" for="slide-1"></label>
                <label class="fs-next-btn" for="slide-2"></label>
                <label class="fs-next-btn" for="slide-3"></label>
                <label class="fs-next-btn" for="slide-4"></label>
            </div>

            <!-- Slide Counter -->
            <div class="fs-slide-counter">
                <span class="fs-slide-counter-current"></span>/<span class="fs-slide-counter-total"></span>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

